# Automated logout of present session to refresh group commands?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command, usermod

So, I'm looking at automating a setup of service instances with AWS.

AWS allows you to run shell scripts on instance creation.

However! I've run into one little snag. I want, on initial ssh into the server, use of the docker command. I'm not really devops, so apologies if this is **Linux 101** stuff (*or a duplicate question*).

Here's what I have tried thus far:

So I have an initial script for setting up firewalls and other bits and pieces we need:

```
#!/bin/sh
$ sudo ufw allow OpenSSH ApacheSecure
$ echo "y" | sudo ufw enable
```

This all works well. My script then goes on to install `docker-ce`:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"
$ sudo apt update
$ apt-cache policy docker-ce
$ sudo apt install -y docker-ce
```

If we stop here, ssh-ing into the server, and the user `docker` command gives us the usual `Command 'docker' not found`. Ok, so I need to add docker to the current user's group:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
$ newgrp docker
```

When running these two commands manually after logging into the server - all is good. However, in my infinite laziness - I don't want to do this every time we setup a server instance.

How would I go about adding the docker command to the $USER ready for startup? I've tried all sorts, but to no avail. Do I need to `$ sudo -i` and run these with root privilege?

I've tried the above both with *$USER* and the `username` specified on instance creation. Doesn't work.

Any pro-devops tips would be greatly appreciated!